# Javascript typewriter() on two lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm creating a basic website, and I used the typewriter function from w3schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp

My problem is that I want to display the text on 2 lines, and I'm not entirely sure how to do that. Anything helps!

Thanks

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum typing effect!'; /* The text */
var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<span id='demo'></span>
```

Comment: What do you mean with *I want to display the text on 2 lines*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to get a `<br/>` in there.

You could do something like this:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = `Lorem ipsum dummy \n text blabla.`;
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    let text = txt.charAt(i);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text=== "\n" ? "<br/>": text;
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<span id='demo'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give the areas where you would like to append your text to a class such as `typer`, so that you can target multiple elements. Then you can use `getElementsByClassName` to get all the elements with the class `typer`. Using `.forEach` you can then loop over all your elements (in this case divs) and append the appropriate character to them.

See working example below:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum typing effect!'; /* The text */
var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName("typer")].forEach(e => {
      e.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    })
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<div class="typer"></div>

<div class="typer"></div>
```

Now, if by multiple lines you mean you want your text to break when it reaches a particular width, you can instead use a paragraph tag (`p`) and set a width using CSS:

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum typing effect!'; /* The text */
var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```css
#demo {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p id='demo'></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<br/>` in there.

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;
var firstLineMaxChars = 10

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    var char = txt.charAt(i)

    if (i == firstLineMaxChars) {
      char += '</br>'
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += char;
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what criteria breaks the text onto the second line. You could, for example, simply set the width of the div to wrap on a word. This has the convenience of ensuring that *all* the text will be wrapped no matter how long it is without the need to edit the string.

```js
const txt = 'Lorem ipsum typing effect!... MOAR Lorem ipsum typing effect!';
const speed = 50;

// Cache the element
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");

// If i is not defined set it to 0
(function typeWriter(i = 0) {
  if (i < txt.length) {

    // Use textContent rather than innerHTML
    demo.textContent += txt.charAt(i);
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed, ++i);
  }
}())
```

```css
#demo {
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the / symbol to indicate a line break.

```js
var p = document.querySelector("#example");
var speed = 30;
var string = "Hi there!/How are you?/blah blah blah";
var i = 0;

function typewriter() {
   if (i < string.length) {
     p.innerHTML += string.charAt(i).replace("/", " <br>");
     i++;
     setTimeout(typewriter, speed);
  }
}

typewriter();
```

```html
<p id="example"></p>
```